# Convertir de formato moneda a float con javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo un valor con "$10,379.95" y quiero convertirlo en 10379.95 para poder hacerle comparaciones de mayor o menor que otro valor, no tengo conocimientos de REGEX, por lo que no tengo codigo de ejemplo. Puedo usar varias variables y el método `replace()` pero quisiera un metodo más limpio.

```
function replace() {
    var a =document.getElementsByClassName("woocommerce-Price-amount");
    var str = a[0].innerText // "$10,379.95"
    var str2 = str.replace('$','') //"10,379.95"
    var str3 = str2.replace(',','')//"10379.95"
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: edite la pregunta con lo que tengo hasta ahora

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podemos resolverlo a través de lo siguiente:

- Usar el método `replace()` el cual recibe 2 argumentos:

  - La expresión regular que se ha de verificar para la cadena pasada
  - El `string` que usaremos para realizar la sistitución siempre que la *ReGex* se cumpla

Dentro del código lo que hacemos es:

- Pasar entre corchetes todos los valores que deseamos sean encontrados por la expresión regular
- Usamos la bandera *g* para indicar que la búsqueda sea global

La propuesta es así:

```js
    let precioReal = '$10,379.95';

    let nuevo = precioReal.replace(/[$,]/g, "");

    console.log(Number(nuevo));
```

Te recomiendo revises *los flags o banderas* extra que puedes según sea la necesidad utilizar para completar el funcionamiento esperado; justo aquí.

Answer (score 2):

Te dejo otra opción aplicando `parseFloat`.

Debes eliminar el símbolo monetario y la/las coma/comas, luego convertir el `string`  en un `float`.

```js
var monto = "$10,379.95";
var montoFloat = parseFloat(monto.replace(/\$|,/g, ''))
console.log(montoFloat)
```